# Como poner estilo a un Input file?

Tags: html5, css3

```html
   <input type="file" accept="image/*"   class="file-input"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````css
.file-input {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.file-input::before {
  content: 'Select some files';
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #e3e3e3);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10pt;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
}
.file-input:hover::before {
  border-color: black;
}
.file-input:active::before {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3, #f9f9f9);
}
```
````

```html
   <input type="file" accept="image/*"   class="file-input"/>
```

Comment: Esto es lo que solucionó tu problema?

Comment: @JuanPinzón  Si,pero no puedo selecionarla como respuesta,porque tengo que esperar 2 dias!!

Comment: Coloca algo de información de que hace tu solución, realmente parece que fuera el mismo código que tienes en tu pregunta.